# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_kb_k| < \infty$ $\forall \sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|$ convergent. Prove $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is bounded. For continuous functions?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

So our Analysis teacher has given us this homework:

> Let $B=\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty $ be a sequence of real numbers.
> Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> a) The sequence is bounded (i.e., $B\in \ell^\infty(\mathbb N))$.
>
> b) For every sequence $A =\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \in \ell^1(\mathbb N)$ (i.e., $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$ convergent) we have
> $A\cdot B=\{a_kb_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \in \ell^1(\mathbb N)$

And one can easily do the "$ a)\implies b) $" but the backwards implication is the one I'm trying to figure out.
Our teacher insists on proving it by contradiction i.e.:

Assuming $B\notin \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ ($B$ not bounded) then there exists $A \in \ell^1(\mathbb N)$ so that $A\cdot B \notin \ell^1(\mathbb N)$.

I imagine such an A sequence is constructed from the B values using that it's unbounded, but no matter how many I try I can't find a general way of constructing A.

In addition the second part of the exercise is proving an 'equivalent' result but for continuous functions and I have the same issue...any idea?

> Let $g $ be a Lebesgue measurable function defined on $\mathbb R$.
> Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> a) The function is bounded (i.e., $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.
>
> b) For every function $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ we have
> $f(x) g(x)\in L^1(\mathbb R)$

Anyways thank you very much!!

Comment: The second question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/910781/42969.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\sum_{n\geq1} k_n x_n$ converges for every $x \in l_1$, then $\sup_{n\geq1} |k_n| < \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481717/sum-n-geq1-k-n-x-n-converges-for-every-x-in-l-1-then-sup-n-geq1-k)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1764672/42969.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first part. Suppose $(b_k)$ is not bounded. There is a subsequence $(k_j)$ such that $|b_{k_j}| >j$ for all $j$. Let $a_k=0$ if $k \notin \{k_1,k_2,..\}$ and $a_{k_j}=\frac 1 {j b_{k_j}}$.  Then $\sum |a_n| <\infty$ but $\sum |a_nb_n| =\infty$.